# Creating 3-dimensional transformation matrices in Python

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I have to construct 3 transformation matrices (3x3) that do the following:

-Rotation matrix Ry that rotates 135 degrees about the y-axis

-Rotation matrix Rz that rotates 60 degrees about the z-axis

-Shearing matrix SH with parameter sh = 1.0 (adding the y component to the x component)

I was given the following code to complete:

degreey = 135

Ry = 0

degreez = 60

Rz = 0

sh = 1.0

SH = 0

Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I would work with `numpy` arrays. You can create a 3x3 matrix like this:

```py
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.array([[ ..., ..., ...], [..., ..., ...], [..., ..., ...]])
```

where the dots stand for whatever number (or variable) you want to put in that respective position. For the basic rotations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations), you can then set up the rotation matrices, you will probably need sine and cosine functions; those are also implemented in `numpy`. As an example, you can calculate the sine of 10° like

```py
np.sin( 10./360 * 2*np.pi )
```

so don't forget to transform to radians!

---

At least for me, there's alway a little confusion about what's a row and what's a column in the array. In that regard, I recommend to go by trial and error: you can simply multiply the matrix that you set up to a vector of your choice (matrix multiplication: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) and check whether the outcome makes sense and what happens when you multiply the transpose of your matrix (`my_matrix.T`) to the vector...

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out using NumPy and the resources you linked!